# Keyword for in heredoc in php

Tags: php, html

there is way to put for loop in heredoc in php ?
Because when I but it in heredoc it showed as I write it without execution. 
Thanks for all.

Comment: No. You can't use any control structures in heredoc. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. **[heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** is only a way to delimit strings and nothing more than that. Any other language struct given in a string will not execute. See http://www.php.net/eval if you're hard bent on it

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

Comment: Thanks hanky panky.